# ME3 Eve dies from stress?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I KNOW this has been asked but for the love of God someone please tell me a way around it! My first playthrough she lived. Did not have Wrex from ME1 because it was before I had downloaded the patch to import to ME2. the 3rd play through I had Wrex, paragon'd Eve, saved Maelon's data and let him live and had full paragon and she died. I have replayed ME2 2x hoping it was just a corrupt file but still she is about to die. So I have everything right, have replayed ME2 multiple times and STILL she is too stressed and Mordin says I don't have the data. Also, I did select BOTH options on how to save the data, the one for "Just in case" and they "you should help the Krogan" option. Didn't change. I don't understand. Especially since my first playthrough I didn't have it happen. I know it's a glitch, but there has to be SOME way around it. Because now the glitch carries over in EVERY game.

Comment: If I recall, some of the mission flags within the ME1 and ME2 save files were never set correctly for certain choices (such as going Paragon with Conrad Verner). There's a few tools out there that let you check some of the flag values, might be worth trying one out.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I am new to this. But I posted that comment on that in hopes that they would have found a solution by now.

Comment: Jonk I don't know how to respond directly to one particular comment in this app, but how do I find these tools?

Comment: Probably the best-known one is Gibbed's ME2 Editor (you can find it on Google). Just be aware that at this point it is too late to fix your current game. If memory serves you have to fix the bad flags in the ME2 save file before you import it into ME3.

Comment: What I did is not killing Maelon in ME2, keeping the research data and having a loyal Mordin. In ME3 I kept in secret until the end that the tower was sabotaged. That's all, I never visited her or talked to her too much.